# Update specific node and related children in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First of all I'm really new to Android and maybe just stuck in my logic... I'm trying to work around this problem for days now. I'm making an app, where you can track cigarettes you smoked. my tree looks like this:

[my tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdSG3.png)

When I add an entry, the the time in milliseconds is stored and the difference to the last child. Now when I add an entry, which is before an existing entry(via Date/TimePicker), the data is sorted properly by "time_in_millis", but the "diff_in_ms" is wrong:

[After adding an entry in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyAGr.png)

This is the code how I get the Data from the previous entry to calculate the diff_in_ms:

```js
final Query lastQuery = drLast.child(db_date);
lastQuery.orderByChild("time_in_millis").limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {


      for (DataSnapshot LastDataSnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        LastEntry getLast = LastDataSnap.getValue(LastEntry.class);

        ltim = getLast.getTime_in_millis();
      }
    } else {

      ltim = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

This the Class which handles the Data to populate the ListView:

```js
public class DataHandler {

  //Handles Data before populating the List
  private long time_in_millis, ms, ms1, diff_in_ms;
  private String date, time, diff, db_date;

  public DataHandler() {

  }

  public DataHandler(long time_in_millis, String date, String time, String diff, long diff_in_ms, String db_date) {
    this.time_in_millis = time_in_millis;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.diff = diff;
    this.diff_in_ms = diff_in_ms;
    this.db_date = db_date;


  }

  public long getTime_in_millis() {
    return time_in_millis;
  }

  public String getDate() {

    ms = time_in_millis;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.");
    date = String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(ms));
    return date;
  }

  public String getTime() {

    ms1 = time_in_millis;
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    time = String.valueOf(timeFormat.format(ms1));
    return time;
  }

  public String getDiff() {

    // I tried to get here the time_in_millis from the last child and calculate it, but the app always got stuck on the device

    if (diff_in_ms != 0) {

      diff = String.format("%02d" + "h " + "%02d" + "m", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff_in_ms),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff_in_ms) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1));
    } else {

      diff = "---";
    }
    return diff;
  }

  public long getDiff_in_ms() {
    return diff_in_ms;
  }

  public String getDb_date() {
      return db_date;
```

I tried to calculate the difference while populating my listview in my model class, but the app always hanged itself on the phone.
Now to my question: if the diff_in_ms is < 0 then I have to update the "diff_in_ms" nodes of all following children, because it's related to the child before and not necessarily to the last. How to do so?

Or is it better to calculate it when getting the Data from the DB?

Any help is appreciated...

EDIT: Right now it's running with the Query in my model class:

```js
public class DataHandler {

  //Handles Data before populating the List
  private long time_in_millis, ms, ms1, ltim, diff_in_ms;
  private String date, time, diff, db_date;

  DatabaseReference drLast = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

  public DataHandler() {

  }

  public DataHandler(long time_in_millis, String date, String time, String diff, String db_date) {
    this.time_in_millis = time_in_millis;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.diff = diff;
    this.db_date = db_date;
  }

  public long getTime_in_millis() {
    return time_in_millis;
  }

  public String getDate() {

    ms = time_in_millis;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.");
    date = String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(ms));
    return date;
  }

  public String getTime() {

    ms1 = time_in_millis;
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    time = String.valueOf(timeFormat.format(ms1));
    return time;
  }

  public String getDiff() {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    db_date = format.format(calendar.getTime());

    final Query lastQuery = drLast.child(db_date);
    lastQuery.orderByChild("time_in_millis").limitToLast(1);
    lastQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

          for (DataSnapshot LastDataSnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            DataToSave getLast = LastDataSnap.getValue(DataToSave.class);

            ltim = getLast.getTime_in_millis();
          }
        } else {

          ltim = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        }

        //Calculate the difference
        
        diff_in_ms = time_in_millis - ltim;

        if (diff_in_ms != 0) {

          diff = String.format("%02d" + "h " + "%02d" + "m", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff_in_ms),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff_in_ms) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1));
        } else {

          diff = "---";
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

    return diff;
  }

  public String getDb_date() {
    return db_date;
  }
}
```

But it shows no Values for difference in the ListView.

Comment: "but the app always hanged itself on the phone" what does it mean? What is the behaviour?

Comment: It means as soon as there were entries in the DB the Listview didn't load at all and when I hit the Button to add an entry nothing happened, except of the System Note that the app isn't responding and I could wait or close the app. It was like it was stuck in an infinite loop...

Comment: What is the error when your is closing?

Comment: @AlexMamo See EDIT please!